# How to extract files and filter conditions from DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame that contains (among other things) the names of CSV files to process.

The DataFrame has the file names in first column `FileName`, `FilterData` as second column and some extra columns (treat every column as `String`) as follows:

```
FileName     FilterData   col3     col4
testFile.txt   XF        value1   value2
testFile1.txt  XM        value3   value4
```

The CSV files (under `FileName` column) are available on [Azure Data Lake](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/data-lake/) with total size of 5 TB.

I'd like to read the first column (which is a filename), then I open/read the file, and get the records that match the pattern in `FilterData`.

`testFile.txt` and `testFile1.txt` are as follows:

```
testFile.txt
1,XF,data1
2,XM,data2

testFile.txt
1,XF,data3
2,XM,data4
```

I want to get the data of the file(reading first column from dataframe), then filter the records based on FilterData column i.e. if the record contains FilterData string, select this record(it will always be only 1 record), and then join back this data with col3 and col4 of Dataframe. Below is my expected output:

```
1  XF  data1  value1  value2
2  XM  data3  value3  value4
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. This is what I am trying to do.

The names of small csv files are in the dataframe. So I should read the dataframe's first column(which is a filename), then I should open(read) this file, and get the record which matches the FilterData pattern from DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I asked for. How big is the initial file that you create a DataFrame from?

Comment: My initial file has few thousand records, but my initial file is also multiple files. Looping should not be a problem once I have the logic in place. I have got it almost working. I had some problem for which I wasn't able to use your code. I will post my solution later sometime. Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're using Spark for **large massive dataset processing** (not as a replacement for reading small configuration files)?

---

What I'd do is to `yourFileNameDataset.collect` (see [Dataset API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)) and having the rows locally do pattern matching on the rows to access the filenames and the values to filter on. That's pretty much Scala (not much Spark really).

I'd then `spark.read.csv` (see [SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) and [DataFrameReader](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) APIs) and `filter` by the fields and values given in the *source* DataFrame. That's a mixture of Scala with some Spark development.

### Sample Code

*(not very effective and certainly not exploiting Spark features like parallel processing, but given the criteria it **does** work)*

```
scala> val filenames = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("filenames.csv")
filenames: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [FileName: string, FilterData: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> filenames.show
+-------------+----------+------+------+
|     FileName|FilterData|  col3|  col4|
+-------------+----------+------+------+
| testFile.txt|        XF|value1|value2|
|testFile1.txt|        XM|value3|value4|
+-------------+----------+------+------+

scala> filenames.
  as[(String, String, String, String)].
  collect.
  foreach { case (file, value, _, _) => 
    spark.
    read.
    option("inferSchema", true).
    option("header", true).
    csv(file).
    as[(Int, String, String)].
    filter(_._2 == value).
    show
  }
+---+---+-----+
|  1| XF|data1|
+---+---+-----+
+---+---+-----+

+---+---+-----+
|  1| XF|data3|
+---+---+-----+
|  2| XM|data4|
+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: You are right, I am not processing massive dataset, but small files; but the number of files is very huge, which makes my combined dataset a massive one.
I will try with toLocalIterator. Thanks.